# Universal covering map and induced maps on homology and homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces

I had an additional question regarding universal covering maps. If $p:U\rightarrow X$ is a universal covering map for  space $X$ does it induce isomorphisms on homology $H_i$ for $i>1$. Or if that's not the case does it induce isomorphisms on homotopy groups $\pi_i$ for $i>1$. If this is not true does it work if we assume $X$ is a CW complex. I apologize if these are trivial facts, I'm just trying to fill some gaps in my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, $T^2$ has contractible universal cover $\mathbb{R}^2$, but $H_2(T^2) = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks. But does the result hold for homotopy groups? My assumptions is yes, due to the fact that covering maps are fiber bundles, but I just wanted to verify.

Comment: Yes. See Proposition 4.1 in Hatcher, for example (though he stays in the CW category). The idea is that $S^n$ is simply connected for $n\geq 2$, so the usual homotopy lifting properties make $p_*:\pi_n(U) \to \pi_n(X)$ an isomorphism.